# Pandas - combine column values into a list in a new column

Tags: python, list, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a Python Pandas dataframe df:

```
d = [['hello', 1, 'GOOD', 'long.kw'],
     [1.2, 'chipotle', np.nan, 'bingo'],
     ['various', np.nan, 3000, 123.456]]
t = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

which looks like this:

```
print(t)
         A         B     C        D
0    hello         1  GOOD  long.kw
1      1.2  chipotle   NaN    bingo
2  various       NaN  3000  123.456
```

I am trying to create a new column which is a `list` of the values in `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.  So it would look like this:

```
t['combined']                                             

Out[125]: 
0        [hello, 1, GOOD, long.kw]
1        [1.2, chipotle, nan, bingo]
2        [various, nan, 3000, 123.456]
Name: combined, dtype: object
```

I am trying this code:

```
t['combined'] = t.apply(lambda x: list([x['A'],
                                        x['B'],
                                        x['C'],
                                        x['D']]),axis=1)
```

Which returns this error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
```

What is puzzling to me is if I remove one of the columns that I want to put in the list (or add another column to the dataframe that I DON'T add to the list), my code works.

For instance, run this code:

```
t['combined'] = t.apply(lambda x: list([x['A'],
                                        x['B'],
                                        x['D']]),axis=1)
```

Returns this which is perfect if I only wanted the 3 columns:

```
print(t)
         A         B     C        D                 combined
0    hello         1  GOOD  long.kw      [hello, 1, long.kw]
1      1.2  chipotle   NaN    bingo   [1.2, chipotle, bingo]
2  various       NaN  3000  123.456  [various, nan, 123.456]
```

I am at a complete loss as to why requesting the 'combined' list be made of all columns in the dataframe would create an error, but selecting all but 1 column to create the 'combined' list works as expected.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

try this :

```
t['combined']= t.values.tolist()

t
Out[50]: 
         A         B     C        D                       combined
0    hello         1  GOOD  long.kw      [hello, 1, GOOD, long.kw]
1     1.20  chipotle   NaN    bingo    [1.2, chipotle, nan, bingo]
2  various       NaN  3000   123.46  [various, nan, 3000, 123.456]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to call `list()` on the underlying numpy array

```py
t['combined_arr'] = list(t.values)
```

It should be noted that this produces a slightly different column from using `.tolist()`. As can be seen from below, `tolist()` creates a nested list while `list()` creates a list of arrays.

```py
t['combined_list'] = t[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()
t['combined_arr'] = list(t[['A', 'B']].values)

t.iloc[0, 4]  # ['hello', 1]
t.iloc[0, 5]  # array(['hello', 1], dtype=object)
```

Depending on the use case, it's sometimes useful to preserve the ndarray type.

---

If you want to combine columns **without** NaN values, then the fastest method is to loop over rows while checking for NaN values. As `NaN!=NaN`, the fastest check is to check if a value equals itself.

```py
t['combined'] = [[e for e in row if e==e] for row in t.values.tolist()]


         A     B     C        D                     combined
0    hello   1.0  GOOD  long.kw  [hello, 1.0, GOOD, long.kw]
1      1.2  10.0   NaN    bingo           [1.2, 10.0, bingo]  <-- no NaN
2  various   NaN  3000  123.456     [various, 3000, 123.456]  <-- no NaN
```

A more complete check is to use `isnan` from the built-in `math` module.

```py
import math
t['combined'] = [[e for e in row if not (isinstance(e, float) and math.isnan(e))] for row in t.values.tolist()]
```

To combine specific columns of non-NaN values, select the columns first:

```py
cols = ['A', 'B']
t['combined'] = [[e for e in row if e==e] for row in t[cols].values.tolist()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with the NaN

```
t.assign(combined = pd.Series(d))
```

Output:

```
         A         B     C        D                       combined
0    hello         1  GOOD  long.kw      [hello, 1, GOOD, long.kw]
1      1.2  chipotle   NaN    bingo    [1.2, chipotle, nan, bingo]
2  various       NaN  3000  123.456  [various, nan, 3000, 123.456]
```

Here is a way without the NaN

```
t.assign(combined = t.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list))
```

Output:

```
         A         B     C        D                   combined
0    hello         1  GOOD  long.kw  [hello, 1, GOOD, long.kw]
1      1.2  chipotle   NaN    bingo     [1.2, chipotle, bingo]
2  various       NaN  3000  123.456   [various, 3000, 123.456]
```