# groupby and convert rows into list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the below dataframe from which I need to groupby using id column and the corresponding values should be in list at the same cell. Anyone please help me on this?

**I have this processed Dataframe:**

[image]

**Actual Dataframe:**

[image]

In the actual dataframe, the list values should be added in the new column called **e_values** to the respective **id**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - combine column values into a list in a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898035/pandas-combine-column-values-into-a-list-in-a-new-column)

Comment: Where are you using `groupby`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df['e_values'] = df.filter(like='col_').apply(list, axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

If going from Actual to processed;
You can split, expand=True and then replace the corner brackets. This should give you a dataframe which you can rename columns

```
df['values'].str.split(',',expand=True).replace(regex={'\[': '', '\]': ''})
```

If going from processed to Actual use:

```
df.set_index('id').agg(list,1).reset_index()
```

Comment: @not_speshal  If thats the case he can go the other way thus; `df.set_index('id').agg(list,1).reset_index()`