# Combine column values into a list of unique values without nan in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine multiple columns of a Pandas `DataFrame` into a single column of lists, such that each list does not contain duplicate values and does not contain null values.

So, for example, in the data frame below, columns `A`, `B` and `C` are combined into column `D`:

```py
                  A              B                 C                                 D
0             "KFC"            NaN             "KFC"                           ["KFC"]
1               NaN   "Mandai Zoo"   "Singapore Zoo"   ["Mandai Zoo", "Singapore Zoo"]
2   "Tampines Mall"            NaN               NaN                 ["Tampines Mall"]
```

The best I could come up of this was a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43898233/16801561) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875903/16801561):

```py
df['D'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].values.tolist()
df['D'] = df['D'].map(set).tolist()
```

which would give me this:

```py
                  A              B                 C                                      D
0             "KFC"            NaN             "KFC"                           ["KFC", NaN]
1               NaN   "Mandai Zoo"   "Singapore Zoo"   [NaN, "Mandai Zoo", "Singapore Zoo"]
2   "Tampines Mall"            NaN               NaN                 ["Tampines Mall", NaN]
```

But that still leaves the `NaN` values in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pd.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) before using [`pd.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas.Series.unique) along axis=1

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().unique(), axis=1)
print(df)

               A           B              C                            D
0            KFC         NaN            KFC                        [KFC]
1            NaN  Mandai Zoo  Singapore Zoo  [Mandai Zoo, Singapore Zoo]
2  Tampines Mall         NaN            NaN              [Tampines Mall]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because two `NaN` values are not equal you can use `[x for x in my_list if x==x]` to remove `NaN` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["KFC", np.nan, "Tampines Mall"], 'B': [np.nan, "Mandai Zoo", np.nan], 'C': ["KFC", "Singapore Zoo", np.nan]}). 

df.assign(D = lambda df: [[z for z in x if z==z] for x in  [set(l) for l in df.values.tolist()]])
```

Result:

```
               A           B              C                           D 

0            KFC         NaN            KFC                        [KFC]
1            NaN  Mandai Zoo  Singapore Zoo  [Mandai Zoo, Singapore Zoo]
2  Tampines Mall         NaN            NaN              [Tampines Mall]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df[['Name', 'Year', 'Date']].apply(lambda x: [y for y in set(x) if pd.notna(y)], axis=1)
```

This just holds values if they are not `nan`s.